# Save PDF to specific folder using JSPDF (JavaScript) PHP

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, jspdf

I'm using JSPDF to convert HTML to pdf and I want to send it over email. For that, I need to store the file in the folder. But I'm not able to store it on the folder as "pdf.save('filename.pdf')" does not give option for path.

```
function pdf_dowland (order_id)
{
    var contentWidth = $("#invoice_wrapper").width();
    var contentHeight = $("#invoice_wrapper").height();
    var topLeftMargin = 20;
    var pdfWidth = contentWidth + (topLeftMargin * 2);
    var pdfHeight = (pdfWidth * 1.5) + (topLeftMargin * 2);
    var canvasImageWidth = contentWidth;
    var canvasImageHeight = contentHeight;
    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(contentHeight / pdfHeight) - 1;

    var pdf_name = 'teklif_formu_'+order_id;

    html2canvas($("#invoice_wrapper")[0], {allowTaint: true}).then(function (canvas) {
        canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [pdfWidth, pdfHeight]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', topLeftMargin, topLeftMargin, canvasImageWidth, canvasImageHeight);

        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
            pdf.addPage(pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', topLeftMargin, -(pdfHeight * i) + (topLeftMargin * 4), canvasImageWidth, canvasImageHeight);
        }
    
        pdf.save(pdf_name+".pdf");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like this is possible with `jspdf` as it uses `FileSaver.js` to [save files](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#save): https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/42

Comment: But than, with what is it possible?